# f.write (data) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, linux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk2TU.png)

if i change data = data + payload to data = data + str(payload)

I will then have this error
f.write (data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

So what can I do to change the code to let the script run

Comment: Don't post image of your code, but copy-paste the code in place. And please post [MCVE]

Comment: include the code in the question please. You opened the file in binary mode so you can't write text, bytes are needed. Either open in text mode (remove `b`,) or convert the string into bytes (`encode`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert it first. `data = data.encode()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) file in appriopiate mode, default is *text* mode where `str` should be provided for writing, whilst `b` denotes *binary* mode where `bytes` is expected, consider following simple examples:

```
with open("file1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("HELLO")
with open("file2.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(b"\x48\x45\x4C\x4C\x4F")
```